# Translation of "go from ... to ..." / 从 ... 到

Tags: translation

> Cinderella **went from** rags **to** riches, but when you are already at the
> top, fate is more than happy to kick you down.

辛德瑞拉(灰姑娘)从穷到富..., 可以这样翻译吗？"从"是动词吗？或者went怎样翻译？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My translation would go like:

> Cinderella went from rags to riches, but when you..
> 灰姑娘经历了从贫贱到富贵，但当你...

It is proper to say '从穷到富', but as it is quite succinct, it is more likely to be used in blog titles and summaries rather than a sentense or an article.

"贫贱" also reflects people's social status, compared to "穷".

"went" - "经历", that is still the verb in the sentense.

"from..to.." - "从..到.." 描述状态的变化 (describe changes in state)

Answer (score 2):

从不是动词。

`从`是副词，`到`是动词。went还可以翻译成`变`，`变成`等等

Answer (score 0):

from rags to riches
从赤贫一跃而成巨富

灰姑娘几乎在一夜之间从赤贫一跃而成巨富。
Cinders, almost overnight, went from rags to riches.